# Django: m2m query based on spatial point returns empty dict - but should contain results

Tags: django, many-to-many, geospatial, contains, geodjango

Hi Stackoverflow people,

I am confused with m2m queries in Django. I have a model RadioStations which lists radio stations around a continent (simply name and the available country) and has the following declaration:

```
class Station(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Station Name'), max_length=255
    reference = models.URLField(_('Link'), blank=True, verify_exists=True)  
    country = models.ManyToManyField(WorldBorder)
```

The class WorldBorder follows the GeoDjango example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#geographic-models).

Now I would like to search for all stations in the US.
If I use:

`s = Station.objects.filter(country__name__contains = "United States")`

I get all stations in the US. However, if I now search with a user location, e.g.

```
pnt = fromstr('POINT(-96.876369 29.905320)', srid=4326)
s = Station.objects.filter(country__mpoly__contains = pnt)
```

the result of the query is empty (even so the point is located in the U.S.
**Is that related to the way of doing a m2m query? Why would the results of the query being empty? Is there a different way of addressing the m2m relationship?**

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: when you figure this issue out could you please update with the answer, I'm very interested in finding out what the issue is? Thank you!

Comment: Hi dm03514, please see my solution below in the answer. Let me know if you have any questions. Solution works fine for me, however, I am still puzzled why it does not work the other way. Cheers, neurix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the question is the follows:

Instead of going from `Stations` to `WorldBorder`, I ended up going the other way.
Django allows the reversed look up through the `attribute_set.all()` method.

The solution is to look up which country contains the `Point` with

> country = WorldBorder.objects.get(mpoly__contains = ref_point)

and then look up all `Stations` which contain the country with

> station_list = country.stations_set.all()

Note that the `set.all()` requires a get query, and not a filter query.
More background on the set.all() method can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships).

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to successfully make any geospatial queries using  `fromstr` when I tried geodjano.  To solve my issues I used `Point`.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

pnt = Point(-96.876369, 29.905320)
```

Perhaps you could trying using hte point class?

Comment: Hi dm03514, thank you for your answer. Interestingly, `s = WorldBorder.objects.filter(mpoly__contains = pnt)` gives me the right results. However, `s = Station.objects.filter(country__mpoly__contains = pnt)` is empty. That makes me think that the problem is unrelated to the formstr (however, this function is tricky, I agree). And that was the main reason why I thought the problems originates from the m2m query. What do you think?